# Kotlin - Continue Coroutine after Exception

Tags: exception, kotlin, coroutine

**My Question**

Is it possible to continue a coroutine's execution after an exception?

**Example**

```
try {
    someMethod1()
    someMethod2() //Throws an exception!
    someMethod3()
} catch(e: Exception) {
    //I do not want to call someMethod3 here!
    //I want the coroutine to resume after the exception inside of the original block.
} finally {
    //I also do not want to call someMethod3 here!
    //I want the coroutine to resume after the exception inside of the original block.
}
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but thank you in advance for taking a look!

Comment: I think it's similar as Java, i.e. not possible. It's not Lisp ;)

Comment: That's what it's looking like. Darn. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I guess it shouldn't be possible either. I would argue that if you could resume execution after an exception, the exception wasn't "exceptional" after all.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that it is not possible. The longer answer is this:

Kotlin coroutines let you *suspend* execution of the code only at designed suspension points (using suspending functions). Coroutines are not a general goto-like control construct. Quite to the contrary, it is a very well constrained and tightly checked control flow concept that ensures that you do not break the illusion of sequential execution of the code, despite the fact that you can suspend execution of the code and resume it later.

Kotlin coroutines implement *one-shot continuations* and once the block of code is suspended it can be resumed only once to continue following it regular sequential execution logic, e.g. if the code threw an exception you can still suspend id, but you can only resume it to continue doing what it was going (handling this exception).

Comment: Does [resumeWithException](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/-continuation/resume-with-exception.html) have no association with this?

Comment: Nope. `resumeWithException` does resume with exception, but you can do it only once. You cannot "resume it again".

Answer (score -2):

For that `someMethod1`, `someMethod2` and `someMethod3` must be `suspend fun`. Then all you need is to catch the exception in the controller and resume the coroutine.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean by:
"catch the exception in the controller and resume the coroutine"

Sorry, I'm just a few days into Kotlin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I have never tried to actually do it myself. Coroutines is very advanced staff, you know.

Comment: Suggests a "solution" and says I have never tried it actually ))